# Add Interval on ImaveView like Carousel of Images

Tags: android, image, carousel

I am adding a new carousel of images using ImageView.

My activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

My slide layout_file.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layoutimageViewId"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

My slideAdapter class:

```
public class SlideHomepageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

//**Adapter for slideshow in homepage.

Context context;
List<ModalClass> mList;

public SlideHomepageAdapter(Context context, List<ModalClass> mList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mList = mList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view==object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, null);

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutimageViewId);
    imageView.setImageResource(mList.get(position).getImage());
    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}}
```

Code in my MainActivity class:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerId);
    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mList.add(new ModalClass(R.drawable.banner_eeee, "Title"));
    mList.add(new ModalClass(R.drawable.banner_gggg, "Title"));
    mList.add(new ModalClass(R.drawable.banner_ffff, "Title"));
    mList.add(new ModalClass(R.drawable.banner_gggg, "Title"));
    mList.add(new ModalClass(R.drawable.banner_eeee, "Title"));

    SlideHomepageAdapter slideHomepageAdapter = new SlideHomepageAdapter(this, mList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(slideHomepageAdapter);
```

How can I add interval for auto slide? For example, 3 seconds auto slide between each image?

I have 5 images total. I don't think to add more images on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set a timer like this:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
```

TASK being the method you want to call. After is an initial delay say for example its starts after 30 seconds. and Interval could be that 3 seconds delay to show the next image/
this way you can have a repeating task.
and in your task method you can simply call :

```
private void Task(){
mYourViewPagerName.setCurrentItem(CurrentPosition);
CurrentPosition = Currentposition + 1}
```

CurrentPosition will be the position of the item being shown to the user.
There are other way like using an alarm manger for a repetitive task which you can research about.